# roslaunch Unable to contact my own server

Tags: ros, roslaunch, turtlebot, network

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have  Turtlebot, running Indigo.

I'm able to run rviz on my machine

```
  rosrun rviz rviz
```

and able to see camera input and other topics from rviz on my machine,

But running:

```
roslaunch  turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_navigation.launch
```

Gives the following error

> Unable to contact my own server at
> [http://robot.mydomain.mz:35483/].
> This usually means that the network is
> not configured properly.
>
> A common cause is that the machine
> cannot ping itself.  Please check for
> errors by running:
>
> ping robot.mydomain.mz
>
> For more tips, please see
>
> http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup
> The traceback for the exception was
> written to the log file

I can ping the robot machine on "robot.domain.com", and  from the robot machine it can ping itself and my machine (testing from ssh), also netcat works fine from the two sides !

In my machine I have the following environment variable

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://robot.mydomain.mz:11311
export ROS_HOSTNAME=robot.mydomain.mz
export ROS_IP=<robot machine IP>
```

On the Trutlebot machine

```
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_HOSTNAME=robot.mydomain.mz
ROS_IP=<robot machine IP>
```

I noticed that application/tools running using **rosrun** works fine from my machine and connect to the Turtlebot without any issues, like:

```
 rosrun kobuki_dashboard kobuki_dashboard   <Works fine>
```

While, tools starting using **roslaunch** all having the same issue

```
 roslaunch turtlebot_dashboard turtlebot_dashboard.launch   <gives the same error>
```

EDITED: Replace robot.domain.com by robot.mydomain.mz (to show that this just an example)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249271/roslaunch-unable-to-contact-my-own-server/) by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-02**:
Just to make sure: `66.96.162.92` is an IP you own? And `robot.domain.com` is also a domain name you own? And your "robot machine" actually has the `66.96.162.92` ip configured?

**Comment by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) on 2016-12-02**:
I used only IP before, which I get using ifconfig, but the got the same issues  (only roslaunch not working), then I used machine names (after setting hostnames and mapped IP in /etc/hosts), but I had  same issue, then i created my own DNS server/ domain mapping and the same issue still there

**Comment by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) on 2016-12-02**:
Note: "robot.domain.com" is just example for the question, not actual domain I'm using, which I have configured in Bind9 DNS server

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-12-02**:
How do you set the environment variables? Bashrc? manually when you open a terminal? or some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not set both ROS_HOSTNAME and ROS_IP. See docs at: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables

And you appear to be using the same ROS_HOSTNAME/IP for both machines. That should be the address at which to call back to this specific machine not the same address which is likely why you're having trouble.

And lastly you should use an ethernet IP not localhost for multi computer setups.

If you'd like more help please edit your question provide exact outputs and more descriptions about how to reproduce your setup. Such as where are you running the master? What order are you running applications etc. And please show the output of the debugging suggestions at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/NetworkSetup

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2016-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MZAIADY](https://answers.ros.org/users/28690/mzaiady/) on 2016-12-02**:
Thank you, The http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot/Tutorials/indigo/Network%20Configuration is more clear about this.

Specially 4.2 Verify from TurtleBot to Remote PC, this test fails